# Zend form element use viewHelper as decorator

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

What I'm trying to achieve is using viewHelper to customize my element. I know that it's mostly done by decorators, but I would like to know is it possible to do it with viewHelper only?

Where I want to use viewHelper:

```
$defaults = $_GET;
$defaults['randomText'] = 'Something';
$defaults['something'] = 'placeholder';

$form = new Extension_Form();

$element = new Extension_Form_Element_Xhtml('randomText', $this->view->SpanAdder($defaults['randomText'])); // I'm creating Xhtml element, where I'm replacing content with viewHelper return. Want to get rid of $this->view->SpanAdder part :) 
$element->setLabel('Label');
$form->addElement($element);
unset($defaults['randomText']); // I want to get rid of this line, but unfortunately I have to have it, otherwise SpanAdder result will be overwritten.

$form->setDefaults($defaults);
```

And I have viewHelper, which gives span around my value.

```
class View_Helper_SpanAdder extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract {
    public function SpanAdder($value) {
        return '<span name="' . $value . '">' . $value . '</span>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What HTML are you trying to achieve?

Comment: And what is your current result ?

Comment: Xhtml returns:  

    **<th><label for="randomText">Label</label></th><td>Something</td>**


    Wanted outcome:  


    **<th><label for="randomText">Label</label></th><td><span name="Something">Something</span></td>**

Comment: this right now is achieved by using $this->view->SpanAdder as second parameter in Extension_Form_Element_Xhtml, but I want this $element to use viewHelper itself, without giving second parameter. So overall my element would be defined something like this:

    **$element = new Extension_Form_Element_Xhtml('randomText');**